# Parse+Swift, "-[Swift._NSContiguousString objectId]: unrecognized selector sent to instance" error

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm using Parse and I had a PFObject I was using to represent a "Job". It worked fined, but it was tedious always using setObject:forKey: and objectForKey: rather than accessing properties.

So, I decided to make a "proper" PFObject subclass. Now, every call made to "objectId" gives the above unrecognized selector error -- even calls that have nothing to do with my subclass.

I created my subclass "by the book", as far as I can tell (below), and I do call Job.registerSubclass() **before** Parse.setApplicationId: in my AppDelegate. Anybody seen this problem?

```
import Foundation
import Parse

class Job: PFObject, PFSubclassing {

    @NSManaged var categoryName: String
    @NSManaged var categoryId: String
    @NSManaged var state: String
    @NSManaged var details: String?
    @NSManaged var jobDescription: String
    @NSManaged var location: String
    @NSManaged var dates: [String]
    @NSManaged var images: PFFile?
    @NSManaged var questionSequence: [String]?
    @NSManaged var consumerResponseIndices: [Int]?
    @NSManaged var isPosted: Bool
    @NSManaged var bids: [AnyObject]?

    override class func initialize() {
        struct Static {
            static var onceToken : dispatch_once_t = 0;
        }
        dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken) {
            self.registerSubclass()
        }
    }

    class func parseClassName() -> String {
        return "Job"
    }
}
```

Comment: btw, I just reverted back to my vanilla PFObject version and it works again; no unrecognized selector errors on "objectId"... So definitely something related to using the PFObject subclass.

Comment: does changing `class` to `static` in the `parseClassName` function help?

Comment: Hmm, how about removing the initialize function entirely and calling 'Job.registerSubclass();' in your application delegate before the parse init manually?

Comment: Nice idea, but no luck. The Parse docs aren't super clear on this, as they seem to suggest doing both... Anyway, no combination involving registerSubclass() is working for me, in this particular case.

Comment: oh, and a second "btw", I do have "#import <Parse/PFObject+Subclass.h>" in my bridging header file. And it does appear to be functional, as inserting a typo (e.g., "PFObject+Subclassing.h") gives me build errors.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue before.
You may have this error when trying to convert `NSArray/NSDictionary` to `String` type, so it turns to `NSContiguousString` type.

You can check:

- dates
- questionSequence
- consumerResponseIndices
- bids

to see if this happened.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I wound up using composition instead of subclassing, which has actually turned out to be a pretty nice solution.

Comment: Is there a way to protect this with try..catch? I tired and Swift says 'nothing here can throw an error'. I only had one incident in 10 months...would if..let work? How?

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was :

```
if let countryLocale = (notification.userInfo![Constants.CountryLocale]!.firstObject as? String { code }
```

and solved with

```
if let countryLocale = (notification.userInfo![Constants.CountryLocale] as! [AnyObject]).first as? String { code }
```